# How to check current SQL statement inside stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Please tell me how to check currently executing SQL statement called inside a stored procedure in SQL Server and its rows affected [if DML, so far count like ROWS_PROCESSED in Oracle].

Comment: use `SQL Profiler`

Answer (score 0):

As per the rows affected by DML, you can use OUTPUT clause, for example

```
delete from #test where id IN (1,2,3)
output deleted.*
```

As per how many rows affected

```
select @@rowcount
```

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: Hi,I need to know how to monitor the running SQL stmt  Called in a Stored Proc

Answer (score 0):

> Currently executing SQL Statement called inside a Stored Procedure

Using `SQL Profiler` you can trace which adhoc SQL statement or stored procedure have been hit your DB server but if you want to get the long running statement within your stored procedure then you can use `sys.dm_exec_requests` table like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests
ORDER BY total_elapsed_time DESC
```

For a better reading on this check [Determine the Currently Executing Statement in a Long Running SQL Stored Procedure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2010/01/25/determine-the-currently-executing-statement-in-a-long-running-sql-stored-procedure/)

Comment: Above sys table showing "CREATE dbo.<STOREDPROC NAME>. I need to know which part inside procedure is currently executed and so far affected rows by the SQL

Comment: @VeeraV, check that blog link in answer, you will get a better idea